# Entity Framework Insert works sometimes on one project but always on another

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I went to publish the final draft of an app this morning and when I went to do the Final test everything worked great right up until I hit upload to master DB. once I did this i received the following error

> Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in
>   System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: A network-related or instance-specific error
>   occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was
>   not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is
>   correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
>   (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The wait operation timed out.)

So I went to google and found that it was probably connection string

```
<add name="ChangedEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/MillerModels.MillerModel.csdl|res://*/MillerModels.MillerModel.ssdl|res://*/MillerModels.MillerModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=ExternalAddress.com,1433;initial catalog=DataBase;persist security info=True;user id=ThisUSER;password=THISPASSWORD;;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Which i checked and it looks OK. I tried again same issue.
I created a Console App connecting to same DB from Same location.

using

```
<add name="MyEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/MILLERmODEL.csdl|res://*/MILLERmODEL.ssdl|res://*/MILLERmODEL.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=ExternalWebAddress.com,1433;initial catalog=DataBase;persist security info=True;user id=ThisUSER;password=THISPASSWORD;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

and trying this one multiple times it works every time.

this is SqlServer 2005

Not working implantation:

```
public void Procurements(List<PROCUREMENT> procurements)
{
    using (var c  = new MillerVeneerEntities())
    {
        c.PROCUREMENTs.AddRange(procurements);
        c.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

working implantation:

```
public void SaveUsers(USER user)
{
    using (var c = new MillerVeneerEntities())
    {
        c.USERS.Add(user);
        c.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you using Sql Server Authentication (sql user & password, not AD), is that correct? Were the console app and the web app running **from/on** the same server? Also check you Sql Server instance's properties to ensure that remote connections are allowed and that TCP/IP is an enabled protocol.

Comment: Be aware that the connection string being used always belongs to the startup project, in case of multiple projects solution

Comment: The Console app is running from the same machine as the WPF app. and yes I am using Sql Server Authentication. Tc/IP is Enabled

Comment: It could be the issue suggested by @Fabio Luz or a network problem. About Fabio Luz suggestion when you receive the exception you could print the context connection (in your case c.Database.Connection).

Comment: Does it work if you take the `c.PROCUEREMNTS.Add`into a foreach loop?  And the persist it afterwards? I think that the AddRange is making the connection to the database to TimeOut.

Comment: no, i'm only adding one. but sometimes it works and others it gives this error.